# Forward domain is not rendering in a iphone with responsive template

Tags: ios, css, iphone, dns, forward

Please excuse my basic knowledge. I built a site and with a responsive template. it worked fine in my proofing are and on all platforms. When i assigned it to the actual domain which is on forward it does not render in the iphone correctly. It ignores the responsive design aspects.

http://www.fransproof.acaesthetics.co.uk/  here it works fine and responds on the iphone.

http://bibbyengineering.co.uk/ here which is where it needs to be it does not work fine on the iphone.

Can any one help me fix it. I have   in the head so it's not this issue.... from reading it is something to do with the forward that is set up on bibbyengineering.co.uk

I just havent a clue how to solve it. I cant move the domain we don't own it. Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your forwarder domain does not have a viewport meta tag in its `<head>`. (See, for instance, [w3school's viewport page](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp).)

Initial domain has the tag `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />` but it doesn't help when it's inside an iframe.

Try adding something, say, `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`, so that the `head`in forwarder domain becomes

```
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title></title>
</head>
```